A more efficient and robust algorithm for minimizing an objective with many local minima
Background
Background
I've developed a Python script that calculates the time taken for a ray of light to propagate between two points in a complex medium. Now, I want to extend this script to solve the Time Difference of Arrival (TDoA) problem in that medium. The problem statement is as follows:
Given the known locations of N receivers (e.g., cameras, sensors, antennae) and the time of arrival of a light signal at each receiver, I aim to determine the coordinates of the signal emission. Since the time of signal emission is unknown, I only know the pairwise arrival time differences (e.g., the difference in signal arrival time between receiver A and receiver B).

What I've Done So Far
I've implemented a script to tackle this problem, as shown below:
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
from ray_tracer import RayTracer
from random import randrange

@dataclass
class Optimizer:
    ice_model: np.ndarray # Parameters used by my RayTracer class to model complex medium
    antenna_coordinates: np.ndarray

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.ray_tracer = RayTracer(self.ice_model)

    def _objective(self, coords: np.ndarray, measured_times: np.ndarray) -> float:
        """Objective function to minimize the error between measured and predicted transit times."""
        x, y, z = coords
        predicted_times = np.array([
            self.ray_tracer.transit_time([x, y, z], [nx, ny, nz])
            for nx, ny, nz in self.antenna_coordinates
        ])

        # Compute time difference matrices
        measured_time_diff = np.abs(measured_times[:, None] - measured_times)
        predicted_time_diff = np.abs(predicted_times[:, None] - predicted_times)

        # Calculate error matrix and fill the diagonal with zeros
        error_matrix = np.abs(measured_time_diff - predicted_time_diff)
        np.fill_diagonal(error_matrix, 0)

        # Return the maximum error
        return np.nanmax(error_matrix)

    def solve(self, measured_times: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """Solve the optimization problem to find coordinates minimizing the objective function."""
        bounds = [(-1000, 1000), (-1000, 1000), (-1000, 0)]

        # Use differential evolution to minimize the objective function
        result = differential_evolution(
            self._objective,
            bounds=bounds,
            args=(measured_times,),
            strategy='best1bin',  # Strategy for optimization
            maxiter=5000,  # Maximum number of iterations
            tol=1e-7,  # Tolerance for convergence
            popsize=30,  # Population size
            mutation=(0.5, 1),  # Mutation factor
            recombination=0.7,  # Recombination constant
            disp=True  # Display convergence messages
        )

        if result.success:
            return result.x  # Return the optimized coordinates
        else:
            raise ValueError("Optimization failed: " + result.message)

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define the ice model
    ice_model = np.array([1.78, 0.454, 0.0132])
    
    # Initialize RayTracer with the ice model
    ray_tracer = RayTracer(ice_model)

    # Generate random antenna coordinates
    antenna_coordinates = np.array([[randrange(-100, 0) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(10)])

    # Generate random true coordinates and measured transit times
    x, y, z = [randrange(-1000, 0) for _ in range(3)]
    measured_times = np.array([
        np.random.normal(ray_tracer.transit_time([x, y, z], [nx, ny, nz]) + 10, 1e-12)
        for nx, ny, nz in antenna_coordinates
    ])

    # Initialize the optimizer
    optimizer = Optimizer(ice_model, antenna_coordinates)

    # Attempt to find optimal coordinates
    try:
        optimal_coordinates = optimizer.solve(measured_times)
        print("Optimal Coordinates (x, y, z):", optimal_coordinates)
        print("True Coordinates (x, y, z):", x, y, z)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)


Example Output:
Optimal Coordinates (x, y, z): [-384.46240934  730.54140202 -612.43716286]
True Coordinates (x, y, z): -704 -408 -611


The _objective function computes the signal arrival time at each receiver location for a given emission coordinate guess using the RayTracer class. I construct matrices containing the pairwise arrival time differences and return the largest absolute error.
The solve method uses SciPy's differential_evolution optimizer, which I selected because it was the only one that approached solving this problem.

The main block generates example data by choosing random receiver and source coordinates, using RayTracer to compute arrival times, and passing these times (with Gaussian noise, and an offset of 10 to prove that the signal emission time is irrelevant to the algorithm) to the solver.



Problem & Attempted Solutions
I require a solution that is efficient with respect to execution time, as this will (ideally) ultimately find near-real-time application. Regrettably, though I've tried applying nearly all of SciPy's optimizers (carefully considering each of their strengths, weaknesses and parameters), as well as some of my own construction, I've been unable to accurately reconstruct the source location. This does not improve with additional receivers, nor with less Gaussian noise.
The objective function is highly nonlinear, and I've tried applying a variety of smoothing techniques (Gaussian smoothing, Huber loss, Savitzky–Golay filters) to no avail. No other reasonable objective function does not suffer from this issue. Consider the following plot of the objective in z produced using example data (and with x and y fixed at their true values):

The code posted above, making use of a differential evolution solver, somewhat reliably reconstructs the z-coordinate (getting to within a unit or so in roughly 2/3 of cases, and getting nowhere near the result otherwise) but reliably fails to accurately reconstruct the x and y coordinates. It occurs to me that it would perhaps be useful to write some algorithm that first solves for the z-coordinate (reducing the problem to one in two dimensions afterwards), however I have failed to write one (I've tried e.g. sampling a handful of points from a bunch of slices of z, and taking the slice with the least error by various measures, however this was slow and unreliable).

Question: Request for Alternatives
What alternative algorithms could I employ that are faster, more accurate, and more reliable? I'd prefer an algorithm with minimal tunable parameters, as I want it to be easily applicable to various values of ice_model, bounds, etc.

Edit:
I modified the ray_tracer.py script so as to be more performant, and also played a bit with the differential_evolution solver. I've been able to coax it into reliably and accurately reconstructing the z-coordinate, and oftentimes the x-coordinate as well. For some reason, it rarely accurately reconstructs the y-coordinate.
from dataclasses import dataclass
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
from ray_tracer import RayTracer
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d
from random import randrange

@dataclass
class Optimizer:
    ice_model: np.ndarray  # Parameters used by my RayTracer class to model complex medium
    antenna_coordinates: np.ndarray

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.best_solution = None
        self.best_objective_value = float('inf')
        self.ray_tracer = RayTracer(self.ice_model)

    def _gaussian_kernel(size: int, sigma: float) -> np.ndarray:
        """Create a Gaussian kernel."""
        kernel = np.fromfunction(
            lambda x: (1 / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))) * 
                       np.exp(-0.5 * ((x - (size - 1) / 2) / sigma) ** 2),
            (size,)
        )
        return kernel / np.sum(kernel)  # Normalize the kernel

    def _objective(self, coords: np.ndarray, measured_times: np.ndarray) -> float:
        """Objective function to minimize the error between measured and predicted transit times."""
        x, y, z = coords
        antenna_coords = self.antenna_coordinates

        # Use in-place operations for array manipulation
        num_antennas = antenna_coords.shape[0]
    
        predicted_times = self.ray_tracer.transit_time(
            np.full_like(antenna_coords, coords), antenna_coords
        )

        # Precompute and reuse arrays for time differences
        measured_diff = np.abs(measured_times[:, np.newaxis] - measured_times)
        predicted_diff = np.abs(predicted_times[:, np.newaxis] - predicted_times)

        # Create a mask for the upper triangular part (excluding the diagonal)
        mask = np.triu_indices(measured_diff.shape[0], k=1)

        errors = measured_diff[mask] - predicted_diff[mask]
        sigma = 2.0
        smoothed_errors = gaussian_filter1d(errors, sigma=sigma)
        total_error = np.nansum(np.abs(smoothed_errors))

        # Update the best solution found
        if total_error < self.best_objective_value:
            self.best_objective_value = total_error
            self.best_solution = coords

        return np.log10(total_error + 1)

    def solve(self, measured_times: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        """Solve the optimization problem to find coordinates minimizing the objective function."""
        bounds = [(-1000, 1000), (-1000, 1000), (-1000, 0)]

        # Use differential evolution to minimize the objective function
        result = differential_evolution(
            self._objective,
            bounds=bounds,
            args=(measured_times,),
            strategy='rand1bin',  # Strategy for optimization
            maxiter=500,  # Maximum number of iterations
            tol=1e-6,  # Tolerance for convergence
            popsize=5,  # Population size
            mutation=(1.59, 1.99),  # Mutation factor
            recombination=0.7,  # Recombination constant
            workers=-1,
            disp=True  # Display convergence messages
        )

        # Return the best solution found, even if maxiter was reached
        if result.success or self.best_solution is not None:
            return self.best_solution, self.best_objective_value
        else:
            raise ValueError("Optimization failed without finding a valid solution.")

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Define the ice model
    ice_model = np.array([1.78, 0.454, 0.0132])
    
    # Initialize RayTracer with the ice model
    ray_tracer = RayTracer(ice_model)

    # Generate random antenna coordinates
    antenna_coordinates = np.array([[randrange(-100, 0) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(10)])

    # Generate random true coordinates and measured transit times
    x, y, z = [randrange(-1000, 0) for _ in range(3)]
    measured_times = np.array([
        np.random.normal(ray_tracer.transit_time(np.array([[x, y, z]]), np.array([[nx, ny, nz]]))[0] + 10, 0)
        for nx, ny, nz in antenna_coordinates
    ])

    # Initialize the optimizer
    optimizer = Optimizer(ice_model, antenna_coordinates)

    # Attempt to find optimal coordinates
    try:
        optimal_coordinates = optimizer.solve(measured_times)
        print("Optimal Coordinates (x, y, z):", optimal_coordinates)
        print("True Coordinates (x, y, z):", x, y, z)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

The changes I made are as follows:

Changed the strategy from best1bin to rand1bin, so as to promote more randomized searching (fighting local minima)
Decreased the population size from 5 to 30. Counterintuitively, lower population sizes seem to yield better results.
Introduced parallelization by setting workers=-1.
Changed the error function to a slightly "smoother" logarithmic form.
Introduced a small amount of Gaussian smoothing.
Keep track of the best solution found, so that even if the solver "fails" to optimize as per its criterion, something is returned (oftentimes this something is a fairly good, but not great, result).

The issues that remain are:

Failure to accurately reconstruct the y-coordinate, and at times the x-coordinate.
Performance, as measured by execution time.

Observe that transit_time() is vectorized (one can pass arrays of initial and terminal points), and so may be much more performant if we could somehow trace a larger number points simultaneously.

Minimizing an objective with many local minima is a very hard problem. Did you try to compute the exact gradient? Starting from an origin (x,y,z), it should be possible to exactly compute the time difference dt to reach a fixed detector when moving to (x+dx,y+dy,z+dz). Then you could use more advanced minimization methods (possibly kick starting from your current one)

Can you be more specific about which global optimization algorithms you've tried? In particular, I think that DIRECT might be helpful for you, as it is deterministic.

@NickODell Thanks for the suggestion! I have tried all of SciPy's global optimization algorithms (including DIRECT). I found that differential_evolution was the only one among them that came anywhere near solving the problem, however it is also the algorithm with which I am most familiar, so it is possible that I simply am not familiar enough with the rest so as to configure their parameters "correctly". I don't have any experience with DIRECT, however I unfortunately wasn't able to get it to perform well.
